# Do all plants grow roots when separated from parent?

Tags: botany, methods

Recently I bought my very first plant.

I thought it was doing well because it remained green, sometimes a yellow leave but all of my acquaintances which do know about plants told me not to worry, and remove the yellow leaves.

Until yesterday,
suddenly
a branch of the plant fell off,

I looked at it and it had rot through the whole stem of that branch and broke off.

Quite displeased of course,

Now, the branch is still alright, I guess, the leaves are still green,

now what am I supposed to do?

For now I planted the branch in the pot of the main plant,
I'm intending to get a separate pot for the branch and plant it again,

But I wonder, do all branches of all plants grow roots when put in ground?

If not it's not worth the effort to buy another pot of course,

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear respected person,

I am not a professional botanist, but I adore gardening, and would like to help you as much as I can from my humble garden experience.

As far as I have experienced, not all plants have stems which root when put in the ground. For instance, I have a plant called Bouganville Tom Thumb (I apologise for any spelling error). I once decided to clone this Tom Thumb variety by cutting its stem off and then burying its base in potting soil. I even tried rooting hormone powder (from a gardening store) but it did not root, even after a whole month.

On the other hand, I had a plant called Petunia whose stem I cut off on purpose to maintain the plant's shape and threw the stem into the soil. The stem shriveled, and I thought it died and left it there. However, to my surprise, I found the stem all fresh after 2 weeks only to find that it had rooted into the soil from side of its stem. Another plant called Jade Plant can be cloned by putting its leaf in soil.

I think it really depends on the type of plant whether its stems will root or not and how long the stem will retain its rooting potential after being cut.

If possible, you can try the following. Put the cut stem in a small plastic pot (they are very cheap) with soil and see if it roots (leaves will begin growing). If it does, transfer it into a larger pot later once it has grown. Wait for it to grow big enough to spread its roots thoughout the pot, then shift it into a big pot.

I believe if a plant roots, then all stems of that plant will root. Plus, congratulations on your first plant.

Comment: Hey Taimur, thanks a bunch for your in depth answer and the kindness it radiates... I'll surely follow your advice, I do hope the separates branch will survive, thanks for your elaborate answer and I wish you much fun with your gardening endeavors!!! Best regards, S.

Answer (score 2):

Plants vary wildly in their ability at vegetative propagation. Not all plants grow roots naturally when cloned. Many plants have very slow response time to make new roots, and the branch dies long before the roots arrive, even in good normal conditions, so that it can only clone with very artificial environment.

You will find guides how to propagate your plant by searching google for clone+plant name... Lots of practical information is available online, it normally involves: 1/propagating by cutting new buds and putting the fresh branch underground while still attached to the plant
2/cutting new branches and taking off some of their leaves so they dont dehydrate, they evaporate passively drawing from roots, and putting them in controlled humidity for a week/months. the roots can take anywhere from a few days to many weeks to become visible, depending on species, i.e. conifer vs most broadleaves.

here's an interesting text on the subject:
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30685/are-all-plants-able-to-be-cloned